# Having Trouble creating a method for insertionSort with Comparable[] as a parameter

Tags: java

I keep getting an incompatible type error for my insertionSort algorithm for the first line in the body of the for-loop, curr = arr[i]. Not sure how to fix this, I thought Comparable Object worked with ints.

```
public void insertionSort(Comparable[]arr, int lowIndex, int highIndex , boolean reversed){
    //if false is passed in for the boolean parameter reversed then the array should be sorted in ascending order
    if(!reversed){
        //int[] newArr = new int[highIndex];
        int curr;
        int j;
        //for loop to pass through the array with starting position set to lowIndex and the terminating condition
        //set to highIndex + 1
        for(int i = lowIndex; i < highIndex + 1; i++){
            curr = arr[i];
            j = i - 1;
            //curr is set to a[i] and j is set to i - 1, if curr is less than the previous index then they will be
            //swapped
            while(j >= lowIndex && arr[j].compareTo(curr) > 0){
                arr[j+1] = arr[j];
                j--;
            }
            arr[j+1] = curr;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Comparable curr` instead of `int curr` should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have an array of `Comparable` and you are expecting it to be possible to assign it to `curr`, of type `int`. How are you expecting an object of type `Comparable` to magically become an integer?

Btw, your algorithm doesn't seem to be doing insertion sort, that is bubble sort.